# Cocos2d: Change sprite's zOrder dynamically (using CCSpriteBatchNode)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, z-order

Is there a way to change the zOrder of a sprite rendered by CCSpriteBatchNode? I've tried it like this:

```
[self reorderChild:mySprite z:indexOfAnArray];
```

I get this error: **'If CCSprite is being rendered by CCSpriteBatchNode, CCSprite#draw SHOULD NOT be called'**

I also tried with the zOrder property of the sprite but unfortunately is read-only.
I need to change the zOrder because, depending on the position where my sprite will appear, the zOrder needs to be changed.

Comment: Oh! I solved it. Is not **self** is like this:

Instead of: `[self reorderChild:mySprite z:indexOfAnArray];` use `[mySpriteBatch reorderChild:mySprite z:indexOfAnArray];` Well... Hope this helps for who ever see this :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is probably not the parent of `sprite`. Remember that the parent is the `CCSpriteBatchNode` that holds it, and `self` is, from your point of view, probably the scene.